# error could not find or load main class -eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, selenium

- Currently working on **selenium webdriver** and using **java**.
- I have created a java project as **OneReports** and inside the project i have many java files as shown in the screenshot

[image]

- I'm trying to run the java file through command prompt and getting error as follows:
  **C:\Program Files\Eclipse\eclipse>java LoginOneReports.java
  Error: Could not find or load main class LoginOneReports.java**

At the same time i want to create a task scheduler for the **Test.xml**. The xml file contains three java files as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="TestAll">
<test name="test1">
<classes>
<class name="test.LoginOneReports" />
</classes>
</test>
<test name="test2">
<classes>
<class name="test.OEPR_DefaultTab" />
</classes>
</test>
<test name="test3">
<classes>
<class name="test.OEPR_InternalvsExternalTab" />
</classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

I have created a **run.bat** as follows:

```
@echo off
set ProjectPath=C:\Documents and Settings\amth\workspace\OneReports\src\
echo %ProjectPath%
set PATH=%ProjectPath%bin;%ProjectPath%lib*
set path=%PATH%%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;
echo %PATH%
pause
echo java org.testng.TestNG %ProjectPath%Test.xml
```

- I'm getting the error as **error could not find or load main class**. Please any one can help immediately.

Comment: set the class path while running the java class.. as java -cp <path where your LoginOneReports.class file is present> LoginOneReports

Comment: For one, you're running `java LoginOneReports.java`, if you've compiled it it should be `java LoginOneReports`.

Comment: @Jayaprasad how and where can i set the class path while running

Comment: @Justin Jasmann i tired and getting error as the same **C:\Program Files\Eclipse\eclipse>java LoginOneReports
Error: Could not find or load main class LoginOneReports**

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: compile and run your java class from command line... http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-compile-and-launch-java-code-from-command-line/                                       http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html

Comment: I had my LoginOneReports in this place C:\Documents and Settings\amth\workspace\OneReports\src\test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From command line run the below commands one by one

```
cd C:\Documents and Settings\amth\workspace\OneReports\src\test
javac LoginOneReports.java
java -cp . LoginOneReports
```

You should study the docs on how to run the java program from command line

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html

http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-compile-and-launch-java-code-from-command-line/

Comment: am getting some error when the same code i run manually in eclipse it is working fine.. In the command prompt getting error

Comment: cd C:\Documents and Settings\amth\workspace\OneReports\src\test
javac LoginOneReports.java after this

Comment: eclipse will create a .class file of respective java file when you save the java file. So when running the java file, eclipse will execute the respective .class file

Comment: after cd and javac, run the java file as java -classpath . <class_name where main method is present>    hope the oracle in above answer will guide you better.

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\amth\workspace\OneReports\src\test>java -cp . LoginOne
Reports
Error: Could not find or load main class LoginOneReports

C:\Documents and Settings\amth\workspace\OneReports\src\test>

Comment: what ever commands you have given i tried cd C:\Documents and Settings\amth\workspace\OneReports\src\test
javac LoginOneReports.java  Once run the second line i got 49 errors then third command tried then got 
C:\Documents and Settings\amth\workspace\OneReports\src\test>java -cp . LoginOne
Reports
Error: Could not find or load main class LoginOneReports

C:\Documents and Settings\amth\workspace\OneReports\src\test>

Comment: have you execute javac <file_name.java> before running java -cp . <class_name>?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48429/discussion-between-amir-and-jayaprasad)